# Visual Studio 2010 Javascript Intellisense not working properly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

There's a little problem with Visual Studio 2010 and Javascript Intellisense.

I've implemented a class with some "Properties" and want to implement a "static" function, which returns a new instance of the class after an ajax-request which returns a Json-Object.

Like so:

```
/// <reference path="jQuery/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />
MyClass = function (options) {
    /// <summary>MyClass Description</summary>
    /// <param name="options" type="Array">Foo1 (string), Foo2(string)</param>
    /// <field name="Foo1" type="String">Foo1 Description</field>
    /// <field name="Foo2" type="String">Foo2 Description</field>

    // [...] Some Code

    // Properties
    this.Foo1 = options.Foo1;
    this.Foo2 = options.Foo2;
}
```

And the function:

intellisense not working:

```
MyClass.MyFunction = function () { 
    /// <summary>MyFunction Description</summary>
    /// <returns type="MyClass">MyClass</returns>

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Foo/Bar',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            return new MyClass(result);
        }
    });
}
```

intellisense working:

```
MyClass.MyFunction = function () { 
    /// <summary>MyFunction Description</summary>
    /// <returns type="MyClass">MyClass</returns>

    var foo = new MyClass({'foo1': 'a', 'foo2': 'b'});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Foo/Bar',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            foo = new MyClass(result);
            return foo;
        }
    });

    return foo;
}
```

When I call the function from another function, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foobar = MyClass.MyFunction(); // returns Object of type "MyClass"
    alert(foobar.Foo1); // At this Point, the intellisense doesn't work correct
});
```

my intellisense isn't working anymore (or works with the double-return), because the return of MyFunction is within the ajax-request. If I place the return at the end of the function, the intellisense is working again. But in this case I have two returns. The first from the function and the second from the ajax-success.

It seems that the `<returns...></returns>` only works when the return is at the end of the function. That's bad, because I just need one return when the ajax-request is completed.

I don't know how to deal with this problem. Hope you can help me to fix this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` from inside the "success" callback is not going to work anyway. It'll return from *that* function, but nothing is going to pay attention to the return value, and in particular the return value from the "success" function will **not** be the return value from "MyFunction".

If what you want is for "MyFunction" to fetch a value and allow some code to work on it, then that code will have to be passed in to "MyFunction" and called in the "success" function.  Thus, instead of:

```
var thing = MyClass.MyFunction();
/*
  do stuff with "thing"
*/
```

you'd change "MyFunction" around so that you could do this:

```
MyClass.MyFunction(function(thing) {
  /*
    do stuff with "thing"
  */
});
```

The function would look something like this:

```
MyClass.MyFunction = function (doStuff) { 
  /// <summary>MyFunction Description</summary>

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Foo/Bar',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        doStuff(new MyClass(result));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But the intellisense for the return value of MyFunction doesn't work either. The code I posted works, but I need the intellisense.

Comment: The thing is, if your function is really doing a `$.ajax()` call like that, the `return` inside the "success" function **will not work**. Your "MyFunction" **cannot** return the result of that ajax call, because it's asynchronous.

Comment: Hm, bad news, but you are right. The only way I've found is to make the function synchronous. I will think about it, thank you.